# Calendar view - end date not showing correctly

Tags: list-view, calendar

I followed the advice on a previously posted article, as I did not want all the columns of the calendar event. I created a custom list and set view to calendar. [Custom Content Type for Calendar?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16129/custom-content-type-for-calendar)

The first issue I have is that in the views when an appointment has an end date if lets say 16th, the highlight bar on the view ends on the 15th.  I would like to control this.

The second issue I have is that I do not want Sat/Sun showing in the view and there are no options to change this.

I am not a developer so would not know how to change this using code.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have found that using the base columns for start and end date works. I had created my own and just named them start and end and this did not show correctly.

I will not worry about the second issue of not displaying Sat/Sun for now.